# need windows script to remove a particular column from csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file, delimiter, windows-scripting

I have a CSV file *(format provided below)* with delimiter set to `,` . 
As an output, we would like to remove `column 4 ( Values )` from below CSV.

We need it in WINDOWS batch script only as there is no other scripting setup allowed on server. Server has **powershell** as well but we are not sure how to utilize powershell commands to serve below purpose.

**CSV is as below:**

```
ID, NAME, SR, Values, Status  
"1", "Raj", "123", "A,B,C,D,E", "False"    
"2", "Rahul", "456", "C", "False"
```

We tried this but, it is not working as expected :

```
(Get-Content .\testCSV.csv) | Foreach-Object { $_.split()[4] -join ' ' } | Out-File .\file.txt
```

Expected Outcome ( removed the Values column )

```
ID, NAME, SR, Status
"1", "Raj", "123", "False"
"2", "Rahul", "456" , "False"
```

Comment: At first, clarify what you need -- if you need help with your PowerShell coding attempt, provide a [mcve] (since "it is not working as expected" is not an error description, so please elaborate) and apply the related [tag:powershell] tag. If you need a batch file for free, well, you are simply wrong here as this site is not a free scripting service; hence take the [tour] and consult [ask]! In case you have tried both a batch file and a PowerShell approach, post one specific question with a [mcve] per coding language!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than attempting to hack and scrape your CSV as flat text, it's much easier to objectify it, then select the properties you want to keep.

**test.csv:**

```
ID, NAME, SR, Values, Status  
"1", "Raj", "123", "A,B,C,D,E", "False"    
"2", "Rahul", "456", "C", "False"
```

**test.ps1:**

```
ipcsv test.csv | select ID,NAME,SR,Values | export-csv test2.csv -NTI
```

**result:**

```
"ID","NAME","SR","Values"
"1","Raj","123","A,B,C,D,E"
"2","Rahul","456","C"
```

If your CSV source comes from the pipeline rather than from a file, use [`ConvertFrom-CSV`](https://ss64.com/ps/convertfrom-csv.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the built in CSV functionality of `Import-CSV`, you can exclude the property/column, using `Select-Object`'s `-ExcludeProperty`.

From the [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) prompt or script:

```powershell
Import-CSV .\testCSV.csv | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Values | Export-CSV .\Modified.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

From [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) or a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```dos
PowerShell -NoP "IpCSV .\testCSV.csv|Select * -Exc Values|EpCSV .\Modified.csv -NoT"
```

Comment: Alias for `-NoTypeInformation` is `-NTI` according to [MSFT docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6).  Also, +1.  I like your `-ExcludeProperty` solution better than my own answer.

Comment: I'm aware of the alias, @rojo, and whilst my shortening of `NoTypeInformation` is currently subject to future changes to the parameters, I prefer its use in my typing. I'm more than satisfied, should the OP require it, that they replace `NoT` with `NTI` as you have commented.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q56003792.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO CALL :drop4 %%a
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:drop4
:: all data to 'line'
SET "line=%*"
CALL ECHO %%line:*%1, %2, %3, %4, =%1, %2, %3, %%
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q56003792.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

The `usebackq` option is only required because I chose to add quotes around the source 
filename.

Since all of your data lines contain columns separated by `,` I'll suggest this pure-batch solution.

The preamble establishes directory and filenames to be used. These are customised for my system.

The main meat of the routine is the `for/f` which calls the subroutine `drop4` supplying each entire text line verbatim. The `for` is enclosed in parentheses to redirect the entire routine output to the specified file.

The subroutine simply assigns the parameters to a standard environment variable (as batch-substringing can only be applied to normal variables).

The `call echo` line executes `echo` having substituted the supplied parameters %1..%4 so the string `echo`ed will be the original line, with all characters up to [the first 4 parameters, separated by `,`] replaced by [the first 3 parameters, separated by `,`] - dropping column4.